# Find and Replace inside of HtmlWebViewSource property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have some HTML code (from API) and there is problem with images. Basically they do not have absolute URL, they lack the head of URL (https://www.myweb.com/attachement/) which is quite problem because when I show this HTML code through WebView it's not loading images of course.

So I show you what have I done so far.

```
public ArticleContentPage (Article article)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource(); 
        //Creating header for our article with some structure to it
        htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
                                <body> 
                                    <h1 style='text-align: center'> "+article.title+"</h1>" +
                                    "<h5> Added: "+article.date+" </h5>"
                                    + article.body +
                                "</body>"+
                             "</html>";
        ArticleView.Source = htmlSource; //Adding the article as WebView source(HTML content)

    }
```

Now the idea was to do foreach and separate whole HTML code and with simple `if()` check if this the actuall word is an `<img>` HTML tag which was quite bad idea since the articles are sometimes quite long so it takes lots of time...

Thank you for any tips how to modify these `<img>` tags. Important information is that I DO NOT WANT to remove them, because I don't know the whole adress, I need just edit them (add the `https://www.mywebsite.com/atachements/` part before the original source.

Comment: just set the BaseUrl property of the webview

Comment: @Jason thank you for your response but my intelisense in VS18 says there is no BaseUrl property :( is it something new so I should update my VS or something?

Comment: sorry, it's on the HtmlWebViewSource, not the WebView

Comment: @Jason you are genius it is working! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HtmlWebViewSource` has a `BaseUrl` property to solve exactly this problem.